# Uploadify PHP upload script seems to drop string portions with hyphen

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I have come across as problem that has me scratching my head since a couple of days now. I am using jQuery Uploadify to upload files to a web server. I am using a slightly amended uploadify.php script that handles the file upload:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file-repository/" . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFilename = str_replace(" ","-",$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    $targetFilename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/', '', $targetFilename);
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $targetFilename;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
}
?>
```

This script was working fine until yesterday. Now it throws the following error:

> **Warning**:
>   move_uploaded_file(/home/server/public_html/devhealth-safety/administration/group/image.jpg)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **/home/tdserver/public_html/sb3/lib/js/uploadify/uploadify.php**
>   on line **46**
>  
>  **Warning**: move_uploaded_file()
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   Unable to move \'/tmp/phpYH8nfH\' to
>   \'/home/server/public_html/devhealth-safety/administration/group/image.jpg\'
>   in
>   **/home/server/public_html/dev/lib/js/uploadify/uploadify.php**
>   on line **46**

For some reason the `. "/file-repository/" .` portion in uploadify.php is dropped, which means that the script tries to move the file to a bogus path on the server.

Now, as I said, the script has worked and I haven't modified it. I have fiddled with the folder structures, but the file path is correct, the `file-repository` folder has all read/write/execute permissions and belongs to the PHP owner and owner groups (which in this case is `nobody:nobody`). So I would not think that my tinkering with the folders has anything to do with this problem (but who knows?)

Oddly enough, if I replace `. "/file-repository/" .` with `. "/filerepository/" .` the script throws the error I would expect:

> **Warning**:
>   move_uploaded_file(/home/server/public_html/dev/filerepository/health-safety/administration/group/image.jpg)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **/home/tdserver/public_html/sb3/lib/js/uploadify/uploadify.php**
>   on line **46**

So the question is... why does PHP drop the string portion that contains the hyphen? Any ideas?

Comment: From the code and information that you posted the error makes no sense. Some of the information that you posted must be wrong. So I would ssuggest you to try again and being extra careful making sure that the code executed is the one you expect (clearing cache, restarting the web server etc).

Comment: Precisely, it makes no sense. I have cleared the cache and I have restarted the server. All to no avail. So what I have done now is to rename the folder `file-repository` to `file-repo` and that fixed it. I'd love to know what's going on, whether I have discovered a bug in PHP (unlikely since it was working until yesterday) or whether my PHP installation has been compromised somehow.

Comment: Sorry, strike that. Renaming the folder did not work.

Comment: I got it. The file could not be moved because the folder referenced in $_REQUEST['folder'] wasn't there! Why PHP threw this irritating error message with the left out `file-repository` bit is beyond me. I'm inclined to think it's a PHP bug though.

Comment: One final remark. I just recreated the previous situation (i.e. removed the folder referenced in $_REQUEST) in order to get to the bottom of this "bug". I then accessed the upload script via a basic html file upload form and I noticed that a standard post call to the script produced the correct PHP error message. Until now I had been looking at the script response via Firebug (as Uploadify posts the info via Ajax) and that's where the garbled error message showed up. So rather than a PHP bug, it seems that Firebug messed up the script output. So note to myself... don't trust Firebug too much.

Answer (score 0):

in your regular expression , the hyphen should be placed at last !!

```
'/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.]/' should be '/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]/'
```